# datetime.now() sometimes (in same loop) change format and omit %f(microseconds)? Why?

Tags: python, datetime

From logs that my program wrote, I called 33,5k times `datetime.now()` and 35 times I got datetime in this format: `2012-01-27 21:28:31` and it is supposed to look like this: `2012-01-29 02:20:03.026000`. Why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**

I found it when I wanted to do this: `datetime.strptime(my_datetime_variable, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")`. Of course I can use try/except and use format without `.%f` at the end, but I'm interested what is the reason of this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it may not print microseconds if it happens to be exactly 0.

Comment: yeah I agree but again I'm not 100% that's what it is. One way to test would be to make a tonne of calls in a row and if the ones on either side are large then small you can be pretty confident that's what it is

Comment: After a quick test, you can see the change: datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 22, 25, 15, 999993) produced '2012-02-02 22:25:15.999993' and datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 22, 25, 16) produced '2012-02-02 22:25:16'.

Comment: Did you mean:
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 22, 25, 16, 0) produce 
    datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 2, 22, 25, 16)

Comment: @SuitUp: I meant after converting to a string (hence the quotes ') but sure, that's the same underlying issue.